# How do I get input from a PyGame window?

Tags: python, software-recommendation

I am new to PyGame. I want my PyGame program to ask me for input on the GUI screen so when you execute the program you get the shell and PyGame, I don't want to give the input to the shell. I want to give it to the PyGame GUI. My input can be strings or ints. How can I do this?

Comment: @David Foerster Yeah, i know, but the guys at the pygame IRC said it was OS depending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EzText](https://github.com/ffavela/eztext) is a simple, easy to use library for text input in PyGame. The runtime is extremely easy to include into your own program. You can clone the EzText project into a local directory with the following commands:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/ffavela/eztext.git
```

If you press <kbd>Return</kbd> it will store the input string in a variable, if you modify the source code by adding the string which is marked as bold text.

```
def update(self, events):
    """ Update the input based on passed events """ 
    for event in events: 
        if event.type == KEYUP: 
            if event.key == K_LSHIFT or event.key == K_RSHIFT: self.shifted = False 
        if event.type == KEYDOWN: 
            if event.key == K_BACKSPACE: self.value = self.value[:-1] 
            elif event.key == K_LSHIFT or event.key == K_RSHIFT: self.shifted = True 
            elif event.key == K_SPACE: self.value += ' ' 
            elif event.key == K_RETURN: return self.value
```